# Equivalent of Java's String.getBytes() in Unix Shell (Cygwin)

Tags: shell, java, openssl, binary

Let's say I convert my string into byte array.

```
byte[] byte sUserID.getBytes(“UTF-8”);  //Convert User ID String to byte array
```

Now I need to write a script on Shell that will have exactly the same functionality as my Java code. At some stage I must hash my byte array (using `MessageDigest.getInstance(“SHA-256”)` in Java and `openssl dgst -sha256 –binary` in Shell), but because digests in Java code are generated from byte arrays, they won’t match results I get in Shell (in Shell I simply hash strings at the moment, so input formats don't match).

Because my input for `openssl` in shell should be similar to Java input I want to know whether there is a way to “simulate” `getBytes()` method in Shell? I don’t have much experience in Shell so I don’t know what could be the best approach in this case. Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: Question duplicated from http://stackoverflow.com/q/28112029/7552

Comment: @glennjackman I would say it is duplicated **at** stackoverflow :) For some reason I think that Unix community has more expertise in this topic than SO community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`openssl`'s stdin is a byte stream.

The contents of `$user` is a sequence of non-0 bytes (which may or may not form valid characters in UTF-8 or other character set/encoding).

`printf %s "$user"`'s stdout is a byte stream.

```
printf %s "$user" | openssl dgst -sha256 –binary
```

Will connect `printf`'s stdout with `openssl`'s stdin. `openssl`'s stdout is another byte stream.

Now, if you're inputing `$user` from the user from a terminal, The user will enter it by pressing keys on his keyboard. The terminal will send corresponding characters (as written on the key label) encoded in its configured character set. Usually, that character set will be based on the character set in the current locale. You can find what that is with `locale charmap`.

For instance, with a locale like `fr_FR.iso885915@euro`, and an `xterm` started in that locale, `locale charmap` will return `ISO-8859-15`. If the user enters `stéphane` as the username, that `é` will likely be encoded as the `0xe9` byte because that's how it's defined in the `ISO-8859-15` character set.

If you want that `é` to be encoded as UTF-8 before passing to `openssl`, that's where you'd use `iconv` to convert that `0xe9` byte to the corresponding encoding in UTF-8 (two bytes: `0xc3` `0xa9`):

```
IFS= read -r user # read username from stdin as a sequence of bytes
                  # assumed to be encoded from characters as per the
                  # locale's encoding
printf %s "$user" |
  iconv -t utf-8 | # convert from locale encoding to UTF-8
  openssl dgst -sha256 –binary
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm. And this explanation on _how_ and _why_ it works is the best I've seen so far.